# Как вывести числа в скобочках не через запятую, а через пробел

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[]
n=int(input())
answer=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])
for q in a:
    proizv=q[0]*q[1]
    while q[0]!=q[1]:
        if q[0]>q[1]:
            q[0]=q[0]-q[1]
        else:
            q[1]=q[1]-q[0]
    answer.append((q[1],round(proizv/q[1])))
print(*answer)
```

В ответе должны выводиться пары в виде (123 321), но у меня выводятся вот так: (123,321), как исправить?

Comment: А приведите какие входные данные и какой результат?

Answer (score 2):

Решилось:

```
a=[]
n=int(input())
answer=[]
answer2=[]
for i in range(n):
    a.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])
for q in a:
    proizv=q[0]*q[1]
    while q[0]!=q[1]:
        if q[0]>q[1]:
            q[0]=q[0]-q[1]
        else:
            q[1]=q[1]-q[0]
    answer.append((q[1],round(proizv/q[1])))
for c in answer:
    answer2.append(''.join(str(c).split(',')))
print(*answer2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще варианты форматирования результата:

```
...
answer2 = [str(c).replace(',', '') for c in answer]
print(*answer2)

answer2 = ['({0} {1})'.format(*c) for c in answer]
print(*answer2)
```